# How should I do to find dates and times without taking care of the order in Python?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

```
import re
exp1="2018-7-12 13:00:00"
exp2="13:00:00 2018-7-12"
reg= r'\d\d\d\d[./-](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[./-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0- 9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])'
compDate = re.search(reg,exp1)
```

I have also tried **lookahead expressions** but they don't get to make them work.

Any other solution is welcome

Comment: The simplest way is to use 2 different regexps.

Comment: why do you want to extract both date and time at one go, just use 2 regex

Comment: @akashkarothiya I just want to do it the most efficient way. Could you post your proposal for that use of 2 regex? Thx.

Comment: Note: A regex approach will not cope with bad dates e.g. 2018-09-31, another approach would be to try multiple conversions to a datetime with exception handling.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend avoiding the use of regular expressions from trying to extract dates from strings. If the number of possible formats is known, then simply attempt conversion to a `datetime` object. If the conversion fails, try the next possible format.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

test_dates = ["2018-7-12 13:00:00", "13:00:00 2018-7-12"]
date_formats = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d"]

for date in test_dates:
    for date_format in date_formats:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(date, date_format)
            print(dt)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
```

This has the benefit of skipping illegal dates such as `2018-09-31` and would correctly handle leap years. It is also a lot easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not needed here, it's possible but using `datetime` is easier:

```
from datetime import datetime

l = ["2018-7-12 13:00:00", "13:00:00 2018-7-12"]
l2 = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d"]

print([str(datetime.strptime(x,y)) for x,y in zip(l,l2)])
```

Output:

```
['2018-07-12 13:00:00', '2018-07-12 13:00:00']
```

Comment: This will fail if the order of your dates in `l` are reversed.

Comment: @MartinEvans That's a good point then your's would be the best